# changing image in start and pause player javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that works great for starting and pausing audio html5 player and it looks like this

---

i want to insert that the img of the player will too change on every click and what i wrote is this

```
<script>
    function aud_play_pause4() {
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio4");
        if (myAudio.paused) {
            myAudio.play();
        } else {
            myAudio.pause();
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<script>
    function aud_play_pause5() {
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio5");
        if (myAudio.paused && document.getElementById("btn").src == "btnpause.png") {
            myAudio.play();
            document.getElementById("btn").src = "btn.png";
        } else {
            myAudio.pause();
            document.getElementById("btn").src = "btnpause.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

this is the fifth track ID

im checking the log but their is nothing wrong with the code 
but what I saw that it changes the first track id and not the fifth

`192.185.121.126/~vagabond/coral/` this is the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDs must be specific for each button (img)... you have "btn" as the ID for all your buttons (img).

So, when you call document.getElementById("btn") it is getting the first img (button).

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: aud_play_pause1 is not defined (index):27
onclick (index):27